# AngularJS 1.x how-to implement an API to extend service implementations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I am working with AngularJS 1.x on a web application which should be extended to provide a sort of API to customize some of its behavior by third-party developers. Obviously these developers cannot modify directly the source code of the application but must use the API I provide to extend it.

I provide you an example of the type of extension I want to provide with the API.

I have a page which displays a form. This form is dynamic and it is described by a JSON. There is an engine in the AngularJS page which read the JSON and render the form. There is also an AngularJS service, let's call it `formService`, which has the following methods:

- `getForm`: using a REST API, get from the back-end the JSON describing the form structure to be rendered front-end side.
- `loadData`: using a REST API, loads from the back-end the user data to be displayed.
- `saveData`: using a REST API, saves into the back-end the data provided by the user in the form.

I need to provide an API that permits to third-party developers to customize this service. The third-party developer could:

- load a different JSON to be displayed in the front-end. He/she can, for example, use a different REST call from the one I provide or build the JSON locally, inside the service.
- load a different set of data to be displayed in the form. For example, his/her form could have different fields from the one I provide and so it could need other data.
- save different set of data. Same as above.

**My question is: how can I provide this kind of extensibility to the app?**

The only option I found was to use the [AngularJS decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators) to let the third-party developer to  decorate the `formService` and provide his/her own version of the methods. In this way the developer can extend or change implementation of specific methods or substitute the whole service implementation.

I made a lot of research and I think this is the best "angular style" solution to extend an existing service from a third party.

**Do you know any other good solution to enable third-party developers to customize the behavior of an existing service?**

Comment: by your example it seems that you dont need to change a behavior of the service. You could not reach the goal simply by parameterizing: GetForm, loadData, SaveData endpoints?

Comment: The approach that I suggest is to bring third parties to follow a guideline established by you, for example by providing the form.json according to a standard defined by you, rather than leaving the freedom to change the "behavior" of your service.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question is too broad and I dont think your idea is so good in general, but nvm. You can use $injector:

```
.directive('strangeForm', ...
    link : function() {
      formCfg = $injector.get(attrs.formService).get();
      data = $injector.get(attrs.dataService).get();
      onSave = $injector.get(attrs.saveService).onSave;
    }

<form strange-form form-service="service1" data-service="service2" save-service="service3"
```

Comment: Uhm, passing the service to inject as a string argument to the directive is an option I considered but do you think is very "angular style"? In that case maybe is better to pass a `config` argument with a list of callbacks that can be used internally by the directive to get/save data.